# Is there a python code to concatenate values into 1 cell in excel

Tags: python, excel, merge, duplicates

[image]

This is the image that is inside the csv file in excel. However the row on the right(ID), has multiple duplicates of the ID, however has different symbols(left). Is it possible to write a code so as to look for the duplicates of the ID, then append the different symbols to the left of the ID. 
Before: 
aaa | 1 
bbb | 1 
ccc | 2 
 

After: 
aaa,bbb | 1 
ccc     | 2

So far, I've coded this : 
    import win32com.client, csv, os, string
    import os

```
# Office 2010 - Microsoft Office Object 14.0 Object Library
from win32com.client import gencache
gencache.EnsureModule('{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}', 0, 2, 5)
                                                                    #
# Office 2010 - Excel COM
from win32com.client import gencache
gencache.EnsureModule('{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', 0, 1, 7)
#
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
Application.Visible = True
Workbook = Application.Workbooks.Add()
Sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
#

f= open("gene_test.csv")
data = csv.reader(f)
count = 0
columnA = []
columnB = []
columnC = []
for i in data:
    print i
    count += 1
    Sheet.Range("A"+ str(count)).Value = i[0]
    Sheet.Range("B" + str(count)).Value = i[1]
    Sheet.Range("C" + str(count)).Value = i[2]
    columnA.append(i[0])
    columnB.append(i[1])
    columnC.append(i[2])
    for x in columnA:
       if columnA.count > 1:
           print x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take the input, and 'uniquify' on the 2nd column.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

dict={}
with open('gene_test.csv','rB') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        try:
            dict[line[1]].append(line[0])
        except:
            dict[line[1]]=[line[0]]

with open('out_gene_test.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
    for key in dict:
        writer.writerow([','.join(dict[key]),key])
```

Input file:

```
$ cat gene_test.csv 
aaa,1
bbb,1
ccc,2
```

Output file:

```
$ cat out_gene_test.csv 
aaa,bbb|1
ccc|2
```